# Problemas al leer datos del xml desde java mediante el uso de JDOM2

Tags: java, array, lista, xml, xsd

Tengo un documento xml y estoy tratando de leer los datos desde java, pero cuando creo la lista para almacenar los datos no se guarda nada y esta se queda vacia.

Esta es una parte del XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:T="urn:ticketbai:emision" targetNamespace="urn:ticketbai:emision">

    <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>

    <element name="TicketBai">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="Cabecera" type="T:Cabecera"/>
                <element name="Sujetos" type="T:Sujetos"/>
                <element name="Factura" type="T:Factura"/>
                <element name="HuellaTBAI" type="T:HuellaTBAI"/>
                <element ref="ds:Signature"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
    <!-- Bloque 1: Cabecera -->
    <complexType name="Cabecera">
        <sequence>
            <element name="IDVersionTBAI" type="T:IDVersionTicketBaiType"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <!-- Bloque 2: Sujetos -->
    <complexType name="Sujetos">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Emisor" type="T:Emisor"/>
            <element name="Destinatarios" type="T:Destinatarios" minOccurs="0"/>
            <element name="VariosDestinatarios" type="T:SiNoType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <element name="EmitidaPorTercerosODestinatario" type="T:EmitidaPorTercerosType" minOccurs="0"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="Emisor">
        <sequence>      
            <element name="NIF" type="T:NIFType"/>
            <element name="ApellidosNombreRazonSocial" type="T:TextMax120Type"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
```

Y este es el codigo de java que he escrito:

```
public class codigo_ident extends CRC8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JDOMException {
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        File xml = new File("/home/Escritorio/Ticket bai/Esquemas XSD/TB Java/codigo_identificativo/src/ticketBai.xml");
        
        Document documento = builder.build(xml);
        Element root = documento.getRootElement();
        
        List<Element> list = root.getChildren("TicketBai");
        System.out.println("Sujetos: ");
        System.out.println(list.size());
        System.out.println(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Element emisor = list.get(i);
            List<Element> valores_emisor = emisor.getChildren();
            for (int j = 0; j < valores_emisor.size(); j++) {
                Element campo = valores_emisor.get(j);
                String emisorString = campo.getChildTextTrim("Emisor");
                System.out.println("Emisor: " + emisorString);
            }
        }
}
```

Printeo en pantalla el tamaño de la lista pork veo que no entra en el for y sale que es de 0, como se puede ver al final de la pregunta. Alguién sabe por que no se me guardan las cosas?
Esto es como sale la lista:
Sujetos:
0
[]
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: En tu código pones `getChildren("TicketBai")` pero yo no veo ningún elemento `TicketBai` en tu `xml`. Tienes un elemento tipo `element` que tiene un atributo `name` con valor `TicketBai`, pero no tienes como tal ninguna etiqueta `TicketBai`. Es por ello que no te selecciona nada. Prueba algo [como esto](https://pastebin.com/a4yBxAg2) usando XPath.

Comment: cual es la salida que esperarias para ese xml que pones de ejemplo?

Comment: ¿Encuentras los elementos con `.getChildren("TicketBai", Namespace.get("urn:ticketbai:emision""))` en lugar the `.getChildren("TicketBai")`? Pero no está claro si el fragmento de XML en tu pregunta es el esquema del documento que tratas de procesar o si tratas de procesar el esquema.